# Is the Maxwell distribution a solution of the Boltzmann equation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

I am studying about the Boltzmann Equation for non-equilibrium rarefied gases (dilute gases to be more specific):
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}+\pmb{v}\cdot\nabla_{\pmb{x}}f=Q(f,f)$$

My question is this: is the Maxwell distribution a solution of the equation above?

Comment: Yes, it is a global and local sulution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to be, because the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution is the maximum entropy distribution. If your model does not allow relaxation to the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution it is in conflict with the second law of thermodynamics.